# Must type.__new__ and type.__init__ be passed the same parameters?

Tags: python

I am writing a metaclass and overriding both `__new__` and `__init__` to have (the same) custom parameters. Must I pass the exact same parameters to `type.__new__` and `type.__init__` when I call them from the overridden methods?

It would be useful if that was not necessary, because I am in turn inheriting from my metaclass to specialize it further. In these subclasses I am doing most of the work in my `__init__` methods. If I had to pass the same parameters to both `type.__new__` and `type.__init__`, I would have to override `__new__` in all my subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Python documents `object.__new__` as receiving the parameters that will eventually be passed to `__init__`. So if *Python* is calling your `__new__`, that's what you're going to get. (Except of course for the first parameter, which will be the class in the call to `__new__` and the instance in the call to `__init__`.)

The result of new is checked. If it is an instance of the class, then `__init__` is called.

It seems to me that if `__new__` was allocating data, based on the parameters, then it would allocate the wrong data if it was given the wrong parameters.

So I would say that unless you have a specific use case in mind where you know that your parameters don't affect the creation of the object, you should follow the protocol.